# Query to store multiple data in an array in 1 row

Tags: sql, oracle

Let's say I have a `Users` table that contains a bunch of users with their `id` and `name` and a `Groups` table that contains all the possible groups with their `id` and `name`

*One* user can be in *multiple* groups

```
1 Alice User
1 Alice Technician
2 Bob   Admin
```

How can I select all the users and store their groups inside 1 column ?

The result would be

```
1 Alice [User,Technician]
2 Bob   [Admin]
```

Comment: does groups table contain userid and group name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `listagg` here.

```
select id, name, listagg("group", ',') within group (order by "group") "groups"
from Groups
group by id, name;
```

If your users table has column 'id' and 'name' and groups table has column 'id' (that's user's id) and 'name' (that's group's name), then use this:

```
select u.id, u.name, listagg(g.name, ',') within group (order by g.name)
from users u
inner join groups g
on u.id = g.id
group by u.id, u.name;
```

Comment: Where are the names of the users ?

Comment: isn't the name column it? you example data shows that it is.

Answer (score 1):

You may need a simple aggregation with a [LISTAGG](http://docs.oracle.com/database/122/SQLRF/LISTAGG.htm#SQLRF30030):

```
with test(id, name, groups) as (
  select 1, 'Alice',  'User' from dual union all
  select 1, 'Alice',  'Technician' from dual union all
  select 2, 'Bob',  'Admin' from dual)
select id, name, listagg(groups, ', ') within group (order by groups)
from test
group by id, name
```

This gives:

```
1    Alice    Technician, User
2    Bob      Admin
```

Assuming you have two tables to join:

```
with users(id, name) as (
  select 1, 'Alice' from dual union all
  select 2, 'Bob'   from dual
),
groups (id, groupId) as (
  select 1, 'User' from dual union all
  select 1, 'Technician' from dual union all
  select 2, 'Admin' from dual
)    
select u.id, name, listagg(groupId, ', ') within group (order by groupId)
from users u
      inner join groups g
        on (g.id = u.id)
group by u.id, name;
```

gives the same result:

```
1    Alice    Technician, User
2    Bob      Admin
```

Comment: What about the names of the users ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 SELECT id,name,group_concat(groups) as groups from users group by name
```

Answer (score 0):

Listagg-> it also allows us to order the elements in the concatenated list based on your group by clause. Please find the query below for your reference.

```
SELECT id,name,LISTAGG(dept, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY dept) AS department
from emp
GROUP BY id,name;
```

Please comment in case if you need further clarification.